# How to get current location on flutter sdk 1.2.1

Tags: android, dart, flutter, location-services, google-location-services

How can i get current location on android device using flutter. I have tried both [**Location**](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location#-changelog-tab-) and [**GeoLocator**](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator) plugins the GeoLocator 3.0.0 shows this error on debuging:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

**Location 2.0.0** also throws an error on debugging. There is another plugin available named **geoLocation** but that is not compatible with dart 2.0.
In such a situation how can i get location (longitude and latitude)[once]?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` permission to AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yup. There isn't any problem with permission. I also have used uses_permission plugin for Android 6+ devices to explicitly request permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geoLocator plugin that I installed was using Android x jetpack libraries while my project was using support libraries so this conflict was causing the problem and when I updated my project to use Android x libraries the problem was resolved.

Comment: Can you describe what I should look out for in order to do this?

Answer (score 21):

Follow these steps to get location in both IOS and Android.

1. Add `geolocator: ^4.0.3`  in your pubspec.yaml file below dependencies: tag
2. Add `import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';` in your dart file where you need to get location
3. In order to get location for android add following permissions in android project manifest file

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`
>
> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

4. For IOS you'll need to add following lines in your info.plist file under `<dict>` in IOS project

   `<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>`

   `<string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>`
5. Function to get location

   `void getLocation() async { Position position = await Geolocator .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high); print(position); }`

Cheers!

Comment: For me it is still failing. Getting this error. E/location_permissions(24439): Flutter result object is null.

Comment: still not getting current location

Answer (score 15):

1. Add GeoLocation Plugin in **pubsec.yaml**
   `geolocator: ^6.0.0`
2. Run **flutter pub get**
3. Add location permissions for **Android** in app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

4. For **iOS** add following keys in **info.plist**

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
```

5. Creart function to fetch user current location:

```
LatLng currentPostion;

void _getUserLocation() async {
        var position = await GeolocatorPlatform.instance
            .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    
        setState(() {
          currentPostion = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        });
      }
```

6. Use currentPostion in your googlemap. (define Latlag currentPosition);

```
GoogleMap(
             // onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
             initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
               target: currentPostion,
               zoom: 10,
             ),  
           ),
```

Comment: Number 3 worked for me!  i tried only with one before, not the 3 of them at the same time :)... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible that uptil now you might have found a solution but still I am adding this so that others can get help

use geolocator for getting current location

In pubsec.yaml

```
  geolocator: '^2.0.1'
```

In your dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MapScreen());

class MapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Map",
      home: MapActivity(),
    );
  }
}

class MapActivity extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapActivityState createState() => _MapActivityState();
}

class _MapActivityState extends State<MapActivity> {
  LatLng _center ;
  Position currentLocation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getUserLocation();
  }

 Future<Position> locateUser() async {
    return Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  }

  getUserLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await locateUser();
    setState(() {
      _center = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
    });
    print('center $_center');
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I had this issue because of libraries conflict and updating my project to Android x libraries resolved the error.